# The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk0\DR0 on a virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, storage-area-network, iscsi

The event in question is generated by a virtual machine.

The disk 0 is a scsi connected drive to the virtual machine.

The vhdx file is in the hyper-v cluster which has the storage from SAN cluster.

So basically, the vhdx is on the san cluster. I cannot find the error on any other VM's which has its disks on the cluster. How can I understand where the problem is at?

Can this be ignored as this is a virtual machine and not using a real HDD which is directly attached?